# React: duplicate values only display on first item in material ui table

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to make a material ui table whose body maps over an array, and instead of repeating the values of the items, I would like to have an item with duplicate values only display on the first child.

If the data looks like so:

```
[
   {name: 'x', value: '123'},
   {name: 'x', value: '124'},
   {name: 'x', value: '125'},
   {name: 'y', value: '234'},
   {name: 'y', value: '235'},
]
```

How would I display 'x' on the first line, while not repeating it on the next lines, and keep the values present as well?  And so on and so forth with 'y', etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you want to remove duplicates, based on a certain field. You could build a new array and iterate over the old array, keeping track of which keys you've already seen:

```js
const data = [
    { name: 'x', value: '123' },
    { name: 'x', value: '124' },
    { name: 'x', value: '125' },
    { name: 'y', value: '234' },
    { name: 'y', value: '235' },
];

const result = [];
const seenKeys = new Set();
for (const row of data) {
    if (seenKeys.has(row.name)) continue;
    result.push(row);
    seenKeys.add(row.name);
}

console.log(result);
```

I'm using a [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) to keep track of which keys have been seen already.

---

Based on a comment, the intent was to group the data instead:

```js
const data = [
    { name: 'x', value: '123' },
    { name: 'x', value: '124' },
    { name: 'x', value: '125' },
    { name: 'y', value: '234' },
    { name: 'y', value: '235' },
];

const groups = new Map();
for (const row of data) {
    let group = groups.get(row.name);
    if (!group) {
        group = [];
        groups.set(row.name, group);
    }
    group.push(row);
}

const result = [...groups].map(([name, rows]) => ({ name, rows }));

console.log(result);
```

I've kept the `.name` field on the original values, but you could map over them to delete them if necessary.

Of course, if your data is **only** a name and a value, instead of pushing the row to `group`, you could push `row.value` instead. You'd end up with e.g. `[ { name: 'x', rows: ['123', '124', '125] }, ... ]`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  This works in removing duplicates.  But I am only trying to remove the duplicate name from all items after the first child.  I still wish to display the values from the other rows in my return, however, i only want to display the name once per grouping where the name is the same.

Comment: @alexrumsey Ah, you basically want to group the data? I'll update my answer

Comment: yes, so that 'x' displays on the first item with the value.  Then the second and third item would just have the value.  Then the same for 'y', and so on. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: @alexrumsey I've updated the answer to group by name. If you simply want to hide the name, you can just loop through the elements during rendering and check "do I have the same name as the previous row? hide my name".